# How do I get rid of "Defaulting the following constraints to type ‘[Char]’" warnings?

Tags: haskell

I'm using the Aeson library and the `OverloadedStrings` pragma, but this question is more general. The immediate context is that I'm writing code for a sum type so I have a "kind" field in the JSON to say which variant is being represented. In the ToJSON instance I write code like this:

```
toJSON (Foo v) = ["kind" .= "foo" ...]
toJSON (Bar v) = ["kind" .= "bar" ...]
```

GHC gives me the following warning for `"foo"` and `"bar"`:

```
Defaulting the following constraints to type ‘[Char]’
    (ToJSON v0)
      arising from a use of ‘.=’
```

The reason is that both `String` and `Text` are instances of ToJSON, so the compiler has to pick one, and in this case it has picked `String`.

I know I can suppress the warning with an in-line type, like this:

```
 toJSON (Foo v) = ["kind" := ("foo" :: Text) ...]
```

However that clutters up the code with redundant information. Also I've got quite a lot of these warnings.

I've tried putting `default (Text)` at the top of the file, but that just changes the warning to tell me its defaulted to type `Text`.

Is there a way of disabling the warnings for Text/String defaults but leaving any others in place?

Comment: Might want to edit the `:=` typo (should be `.=`) - shell habits die hard

Comment: Some helper function options:  `text :: Text -> Text ; text = id` and `"kind .= text "foo"`.  Or consider `(..=) :: KeyValue kv => Text -> Text -> kv` and `"kind" ..= "foo"`.   I agree this is a broken corner of the language and have long wanted better defaulting that doesn't result in warnings.

Comment: @JordanMackie Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Why not lift that part of the serialisation logic out into a separate function? It's kind of hacky anyway, so better to section it off. And you'll silence the warning (provided you give the function a type).

Something along the lines of...

```
toJSON thing@(Foo v) = ["kind" .= kind thing ...]
toJSON thing@(Bar v) = ["kind" .= kind thing ...]

kind :: T -> Text
kind (Foo _) = "foo"
kind (Bar_)  = "bar"
```

However you want to to do it. Maybe use a `ViewPattern` or maybe make `kind :: KeyValue kv => T -> kv`. Just don't inline it, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I took Thomas DuBuisson's suggestion from the comments and added a couple of specialized functions:

```
 -- | Type-restricted version of "(.=)" to silence compiler warnings about defaults.
 (..=) :: (KeyValue kv) => Text -> Text -> kv
 (..=) = (.=)


 -- | Type restricted version of "(.:)" to silence compiler warnings about defaults.
 (..:) :: Object -> Text -> Parser Text
 (..:) = (.:)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd probably abstract the key-value pair you're making, like this:

```
kind :: KeyValue kv => Text -> kv
kind lbl = "kind" .= lbl

toJSON (Foo v) = [kind "foo", ...]
toJSON (Bar v) = [kind "bar", ...]
```